# Using back camera for AR while simultaneously capturing input with the front camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm wondering if something like this is possible with ARFoundation.
From what I've read it's possible to record with front and back cameras simultaneously with the latest iPhones (XS+). I've also read that a limit set of Android devices support simultaneous use of front and back cameras.

However, I haven't been able to get anything to work. Using the AR Session camera immediately disables a WebCamTexture that is playing from my front cam device (tested on pixel 3)

My specific use case is to manipulate AR imagery depending on the user's emotional response. The front camera just needs to snapshot this information so that I can send it to be processed by AWS' Rekognition API.

Is what I'm trying to achieve simply not possible with a single device?

Comment: It seems like you can't get a video stream from the front camera at the same time as the back camera. However you might get the facial data from your front camera at the same time. At least that is what I understood from [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/arfoundation-samples/issues/215). But I may be wrong, I'm not familiar with AR.